# Access database dataset not updating unless i close and reopen program

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I have a dataset in my app that is linked to an Access database, I am then reading from the `dataset` and displaying the data in a `chart`.

I was previously using a SQL server Database; however I wanted my app to work on any device it was installed on so I used a local access database file that get bundle with the app.

My issue is when the Access database has new entries written into it, hitting the refresh button in my program doesn’t reflect these changes in the chart, the only way to see the new entries is to close and re-open my program. 
This is the code I am using to display/refresh the data.

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GlobalButton = button1;
        battremTableAdapter.Fill(buoyDBDataSet.battrem);
        ChartDisplay(buoyDBDataSet.battrem.AsEnumerable().Reverse().Take(Trackbarvalue).Reverse(),
            "Battery Remaining", buoyDBDataSet.battrem.numColumn.ToString(),
            buoyDBDataSet.battrem.battremainColumn.ToString());
    }




 private void ChartDisplay(object datasource, string series, string xvalue, string yvalue)
        {
            chart2.DataSource = datasource;
            chart2.Series.Clear();
            chart2.Series.Add(series);
            chart2.Series[series].XValueMember = xvalue;
            chart2.Series[series].YValueMembers = yvalue;
            chart2.Series[series].IsXValueIndexed = true;
            chart2.Series[series].BorderWidth = 5;
            chart2.Series[series].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            chart2.Visible = true;
        }
```

This code worked perfectly when using a SQL Server Database but now I have moved to a Access database it doesn’t refresh.

How can I get this to refresh on each button click?

EDIT:

This is the only code that runs `Form1_Load` that has anything to do with the chart.

```
     //Setting up the chart
        chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        chart2.Visible = false;
        chart2.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
        chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;

        //Setting up trackbar 
        trackBar1.Value = 10;
        trackBar1.Minimum = 10;
        trackBar1.Maximum = 100;
        Trackbarvalue = 10;
        trackBar1.ValueChanged += trackBar1_ValueChanged;
```

Comment: As an aside, MS Access won't solve your portability problems. You still need a runtime installed. You might look at SQLite.

Comment: what code is running to bind the chart when you reopen the program?

Comment: @Crowcoder i answered your question in a edit. But that was my first point of call, is there must be something that runs on start that gets the data, but there isnt.

Comment: If you do nothing other than switch to MSSQL you're saying it works?

Comment: @Crowcoder Correct, the code stays exactly the same, as i am using `data sources` and `tableadapters`